# Issue in making Https request from Mule with TLS v1.2 and without SSL certificate verification

Tags: mule, tls1.2, outbound

I want to make a https request with a TLS v1.2.
I found a property as follows:

```
<tls:context name="trustallcertificate" enabledProtocols="TLSv1.2">
    <tls:trust-store insecure="true" />
</tls:context>
```

But it is for `<http:listener-config name="globalConfig" protocol="HTTPS" host="localhost" port="8443">`

Is there a similar configuration for a outbound request.
I tried with '`<spring:property name="sslType" value="TLSv1.2"/>`'
But following error came:

> org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Line 127 in XML document
>   from ConnectToIssuer.xml is invalid; nested exception is
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 127; columnNumber: 54;
>   cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'spring:property'. One of
>   '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https":tls-protocol-handler}'
>   is expected. (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll have to configure a global `request-config` instead of a `listener-config` such as:

```
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" ... >
    <tls:context name="trustallcertificate" enabledProtocols="TLSv1.2">
        <tls:trust-store insecure="true" />
    </tls:context>
</http:request-config>
```

And make a request in your flow:

```
<flow name="someflow">
    ...
    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" .../>
    ...
</flow>
```